# How do I find the installation director of 'make' in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, make

How do I find the installation director of 'make' in windows 10?

I have it on the command line, by typing `make` so I know it is definitely installed.

I can't find it installed in apps in windows 10 settings.

I can't find it by manually going through my environment variables.

Is there a command I can type in make to determine where on my system it is installed?

Comment: Assuming "make" is the name of a program and its executable is an .exe file, you could type "DIR make.exe /s" from a command prompt.

Comment: yeah its not finding it that way, strange...

Comment: Well, it could be a .com file, though those are generally small programs, but I've seen some programs that use a .com program to launch a .exe file.

Comment: actually found it, nw if you put your answer as an answer I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "make" is the name of a program and its executable is an .exe file, you could type "DIR make.exe /s" from a command prompt. In case the program launches from a .com program, you can type "DIR make.com /s" also. Though .com programs are generally small, they can be used to launch .dll files or other .exe files.

Answer (score -1):

On the off chance that they end up battling to address the worries and show that they are being heard, raising to a supervisor is a sensible game-plan. Some of the time, every one of them a client need is to realize that they aren't simply one more number. Commonly, in one moment or two of a visit with an unrivalled, the information that they aren't being disregarded by the business is everything necessary.